# How to fill a list in Elixir with similar method like for loops in other languages

Tags: arrays, list, elixir

I would like to make a list with 2 integer in Elixir like this:

```elixir
@type pairs::{i:: integer, j::integer}

@spec my_list(i:: integer, j::integer) :: res::[pairs]
def my_list(i, j) do
  ...
end
```

If `i=3` and `j=2` I would like to get this form: `[{1,1},{1,2},{2,1},{2,2},{3,1},{3,2}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after [`for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension.

```elixir
for i <- 1..3, j <- 1..2, do: {i, j}
```

Please note, that there are also many other ways to accomplish this task, like `Enum` and/or `Stream` modules functions.